# Different servlet-api versions collision

Tags: rest, maven, jetty, servlet-filters

I'm developing RestEasy web services using Maven and Jetty as the server. One of the services should use Filter that extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper. The problem is in method setCharacterEncoding of the interface javax.servlet.ServletResponse which comes from servlet-api 2.3. I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.webapp.rest.jsonp.HttpServletResponseContentWrapper.setCharacterEncoding(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I've speficied servlet-api 2.4 dependency as this, but also tried with 2.5:

```
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Servlet-api 2.4 is specified like this:

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I'm using Maven jetty plugin:

```
 <plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.1.15</version>
<configuration>
 ....
 <exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

My RestEasy configuration:

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2.GA</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
```

However, in maven repository there are always both 2.3 and 2.4 (or 2.5) versions. I can't figure out if this 2.3 version comes with some other dependency. Is there any suggestion how could I find out this and how to enforce servlet-api 2.4 to be used.

My dependency tree looks is as follow:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.inextweb.ai:inextweb-ai:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.htmlparser:htmlparser:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.htmlparser:htmllexer:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.htmlparser:thumbelina:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.htmlparser:sitecapturer:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.htmlparser:filterbuilder:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jung:jung-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.collections:collections-generic:jar:4.01:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jung:jung-algorithms:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- colt:colt:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jung:jung-graph-impl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jung:jung-visualization:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-tools:jar:1.5.2-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-maxent:jar:3.0.2-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  \- jwnl:jwnl:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jwordnet:jwnl:jar:1.4_rc3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:2.2.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:jar:2.2.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:2.2.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.simpleframework:simple-xml:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:system
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:140:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile
[INFO] |     \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here is the whole [pom.xml](http://goo.gl/8uJ3W) and [web.xml](http://goo.gl/2CeQy)

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, is this `com.webapp.` package something that you wrote? Are you getting this error at runtime or compile time? If at runtime, what container (specific version please) are you deploying to? Can you please post the relevant dependencies in your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: com.webapp. is my code. The error happens in runtime, exactly when specific restful service having to provide jsonp is called. I updated my original post so it contains additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the problem here. In maven-jetty-plugin I added dependency for commons-logging which pulled servlet-api 2.3 each time I run jetty. Once I removed this dependency, everything was fine.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [servlet api javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/package-summary.html)...

[javax.servlet.HttpSevletResponseWrapper.setCharacterEncoding(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) has existed since Servlet API 2.4.

You have a few things to take care of.

1. Set your Servlet API version in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`
2. Ensure you use the appropriate Servlet API in your project for the version of Jetty you intend on running on.

   - Jetty 6 - Servlet API 2.4
   - Jetty 7 - Servlet API 2.5
   - Jetty 8 - Servlet API 3.0
   - Jetty 9 - Servlet API 3.1
3. Grab the appropriate Servlet API jar file from maven

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <dependencies>

      <!-- Servlet API 2.4 -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet API 2.5 / Standard Location -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet API 2.5 / OSGi bundle ready -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.v201103041518</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet API 3.0 / Standard Location / OSGi bundle ready -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet API 3.1 / Standard Location / OSGi bundle ready -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know all these details. However, I checked these and it didn't work. I updated my previous post so you can see my configuration. I'm confused with this servlet-api 2.3 which shows up in maven repository after the application compiles. Do you have idea where could it come from?

Comment: Without seeing your build it would be impossible to say.  Its likely arriving from a direct dependency or a transitive one. Use `$ mvn dependency:tree` to see the tree of dependencies that are resolved, it might help you see where that specific dependency is arriving in via.

Comment: I added dependency tree in my post. I also added a link to the whole pom.xml and web.xml. I don't understand what is going on. Dependency tree shows version 2.5 only, but I explicitly added 2.4 in pom.xml. Moreover, there is 2.3 in repository, and I can't see it in dependency tree.

Comment: The mere existence of artifact in `$HOME/.m2/repository` has absolutely no bearing on your current active project.  Don't pay attention to `$HOME/.m2/repository` it is just a local cache for artifacts for all maven projects on your system.  Only the artifacts that you declare and are part of your projects dependency tree are used.

Comment: And again, you _cannot_ use Servlet API 2.3.  Your initial error message and the javadoc make that very clear.  You _must_ use Servlet Api 2.4 (or newer) for that specific error message to be fixed.

Comment: If I delete all servlet versions from repository and compile the project then all three versions of api are downloaded, so I suppose it must be related to the current project, and not some other project. I'm aware of that I cannot use Servlet API 2.3, but how can I enforce the use of 2.4 or higher? If you look at my configuration, you can see that   Servlet API 2.4 is configured in both, web.xml and pom.xml, so I don't see any reason for Servlet api 2.3 to be referenced from the project.