# javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection error

Tags: java, jetty, nosuchmethoderror

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.mstack.hub.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:47) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection;
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:92) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.adaptToMultipartHttpServletRequest(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.resolveMultipartArgument(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:102) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:98) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
```

I am getting this error when I run my web service in which I am sending a multipart file as part of request. I did refer this link - [Facing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343725/facing-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-httpservletrequest-getpartsljava-util-coll)   but I am using javax.servlet api of version 3.1 and I checked in my WEB-INF/libs folder too. There is only one jar of javax.servlet api which of version 3.1. I checked my web.xml too, even there I have version number as 3.1. However I have a small doubt, In the stacktrace there I saw this:

```
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
```

this line shows a jetty 6.1.25 jar whereas I am using javax-servlet version 3.1. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: The servlet jar must NOT be inside your webapp. The servlet container provides it, and provides an implementation of all the interfaces it contains. But of course, you can't use methods introduced in 3.1 if your servlet container doesn't support that version yet. Upgrade jetty to a version that supports the 3.1 version of the API: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: I am using java 8 and javax-servlet.jsp 2.3.1 jar but still it doesnt work out. According to the link given above I have all the pre-requisites(javax-servlet version 3.1, java 8, web.xml defined version 3.1 and javax-servlet.jsp jar version 2.3.1); still I am not able to resolve the issue

Comment: If you want to use servlet 3.1 methods, you need a web server that supports servlet 3.1. Jetty 6 only supports servlet 2.6. As simple as that. Just like you can't run a program using streams, introduced in Java 8, on a Java 6 VM, where streams don't exist yet.

Comment: @JBNizet minor correction, Jetty 6 supports Servlet 2.5 (there is no Servlet 2.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--) you will need a Servlet Container that supports Servlet 3.0 (or better).

The first version of Jetty for Servlet 3.0 support was Jetty 8 (now EOL/End of Life).

The current (supported version) of Jetty is 9.x, with the most recent release being version `9.3.12.v20160915` (which supports Servlet 3.1)